# Websites for car relocation in Europe?

Tags: europe, online-resources, international-travel, car-rentals, automobiles

Is there a good website for car/camper relocation in Europe ?
I mean, those companies that allow you to rent a car/camper for free from point A to point B.

Let's say between Netherlands and Italy/Spain?

Comment: Do you mean *specifically* for international rentals?  I know sites for specific countries...

Comment: @gerrit yeah, to rent a car for free or almost free, from a country to another

Answer (score 1):

[Transfercar4u.no](http://www.transfercar4u.no/freecar.asp) offers this sort of service within Norway, though it is more focused on regular cars instead of camping cars

Answer (score 0):

This is the only one I found, but there are barely offers:
http://www.imoova.com/imoova/relocations